# Reorder MySQL rows: move row "up"

Tags: mysql

I have a `MySQL` table where rows are inserted in a given order by the user. If the user then forgets to add a row and inserts it later it will come after the others that are already inserted, also when performing simple query. The order of insertion is the order I want the elements to be retreived. The table in question is a simple table resolving a many-to-many relationship with two IDs (`recipe_id` and `ingredient_id`).

```
mysql> select * from ingredient_in_recipe where recipe_id = 7;
+-----------+---------------+------+----------+------------+
| recipe_id | ingredient_id | unit | quantity | group_name |
+-----------+---------------+------+----------+------------+
|         7 |            71 | g    |   300.00 | NULL       |
|         7 |            34 | stk  |     3.00 | NULL       |
|         7 |            72 | stk  |     1.00 | NULL       |
|         7 |            73 | stk  |     0.50 | NULL       |
|         7 |            45 | stk  |     6.00 | NULL       |
|         7 |            74 | stk  |     0.50 | NULL       |
|         7 |            23 | g    |    15.00 | NULL       |
|         7 |            78 | ts   |     2.00 | NULL       |
|         7 |            75 | ts   |     3.00 | NULL       | <--- This is where I want the last element to be.
|         7 |            76 | ss   |     1.00 | NULL       |
|         7 |            77 | stk  |     1.00 | NULL       |
|         7 |            79 | g    |   195.00 | NULL       |
|         7 |            38 | ss   |     5.00 | NULL       | <--- This is inserted later. Should be "higher up".
+-----------+---------------+------+----------+------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any point in the data where you can see which insert has to be at a specific line?

Comment: Also: You could give your table an order_id which you let the user choose from. E.g. the user could pick "Place at [] line". You for yourself would then only need to order by order_id.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no data telling which line a specific row should be at. It is only the order of insertion that matters (currently). Several rows may also be inserted simultaneously, and then that order is what counts. Hence, it is not really useful with a timestamp either. I guess adding an `order_id` or similar could work, but it would increase the complexity a bit. Thus I would really just reorder the data if possible when an erroneous insertion occurs. (This is a small project and insertions are not really frequent.)

Comment: Dude. If the data isnt pointing out the correct order in any way and the user may not choose the order manually, there is nothing left.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. I was just wondering if something like this actually is possible without adding anything to the database/table. So I guess the answer to `Is there a simple way to achieve this?` is `No, it is not.`.

Comment: "The order of insertion is the order I want the elements to be retreived." -- Without an explicit data field to order by no RDBMS I know will assert *any* particular order in which records are returned; this includes the possibility that records may change their relative order from time to time as the RDBMS does internal "maintenance".

Comment: Yes, maybe I have to go with an ordering column after all to be precise and to avoid future horrors. Do you by chance know when/how such maintenance is done?

Comment: You could use autoincrement and leave a blank field for this column when inserting. It would automatically raise the last id by 1 and tag your new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @C4ud3x and @Hanno Binder, there is no guarantee that `MySQL` returns the data in the same order as they were inserted. Normally, this is the case, but it is not a robust way to handle ordering of the data. Thus I solved the problem by adding a column `order_id` to be able to use the `ORDER BY` clause to ensure that the order will be maintained properly.

I found a good answer to a related question over at [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql). The main point from the accepted answer there is:

*If, on the other hand, you intend to rely on this order for anything, you must specify your desired order using `ORDER BY`. **To do anything else is to set yourself up for unwelcome surprises.***